# wp7 mediaelement stops when unplugging the headset

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using a mediaelement and when the headset is unplugged I get a mediafailed event with NullReferenceException. Since the media element stream is not working anymore, I want to be able to distinguish this case and to handle it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the windows phone 7 design that when you unplug a headset or your headphones that the music player or other apps using the mediaelement should pause.

You can have a look at the CurrentStateChanged event to see if the state of the MediaElement is changed.

docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.currentstatechanged%28VS.95%29.aspx